$A = \left\{ \frac{x}{x+1} : x > 0 \right\}$. Prove inf $A$ = $0$.
$A = \left\{ \frac{x}{x+1} : x > 0 \right\}$
The set A is bounded, because  $0 < 1 - \frac{1}{x+1} < 1$ for all $ x > 0 $.
My attempt:
inf $A$ = $0$, because:

$ 0 < 1 - \frac{1}{x+1}$ for all $ x > 0 $, so $ 0 $ is a lower bound of $A$.

For any $ w > 0 $, $w$ is not a lower bound of $ A $. By the Archimedean property, there exists $ x_0 \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $\frac{1}{x_0} < w $. Consequently, there exists $a_1 = 1 - \frac{1}{x_0 + 1}\in A$ such that:
$ a_1 = 1 - \frac{1}{x_0+1}<\frac{1}{x_0} < w$.


Is this step correct? In no. 2 want to show  there exist $a_1∈A$ such that $a_1<w$.

No, the inequality for $a_1$ is wrong in general. When $x_0$ is large, $1/x_0$ is very closed to $0$ while $a_1$ is closed to $1$.

Note that ${x \over 1+x } \le x$. Just choose $x={w \over 2}$.

@copper.hat So, I can choose $x = \frac{w}{2} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{\frac{w}{2}} = \frac{2}{w} < w$, which implies $a_0 < \frac{2}{w} < w$. Is this correct?

@mathstudent I don't know what $a_0$ is meant to be. This just shows that any $w>0$ cannot be a lower bound. Since $0$ is a lower bound, this establishes that the $\inf$ is $0$.

Sorry, there was a typo. It should be $a_1$ because I want to show that there exist $a_1 \in A$ such that $a_1 < w$.

Say $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$
Observe
$$\frac{x}{x+1}=1-\frac{1}{x+1}$$
Since $\frac{1}{x+1}$ is a decreasing sequence, so $f(x)$ is a increasing sequence
So, the infimum is simply-
$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=0$$
So the infimum is 0 $\blacksquare$

Note that for $x>0$, $\frac{x}{x+1}$ is also positive, so $0$ is trivially a lower bound of the set. Let $\epsilon\in (0,1)$ be given, then solve the inequality $\frac{x}{x+1}< \epsilon$ for $x$. This is side-work. Scrap it all when you are done, but you'll use them to actually write your answer.
You now know how to choose $x$ based on the inequality you have solved, and verify that it works to show that $\epsilon$ is not a lower bound. You will likely need Archimedean Principle to justify being able to choose the $x$ that you have chosen.
Get used to these "magic" proofs by conjuring up the thing that works after you've done a bunch of side-work no one should ever see. They are quite common in analysis.
Edit: There is a quick answer in the comments, the above works as a general procedure for all problems of this type you might encounter in an introductory analysis course.
